# Use a Adobe Fireworks file extension other than .PNG for multi-layer master files

Tags: file, adobe, fireworks

Adobe Fireworks saves both the master (multi layered source files) as flattened web-optimized graphics in the .png file format.

This is confusing in my workflow and sometimes the master .png file gets overwritten by a flattened web-optimized file with the same filename.

I have adopted the convention to ad _FW to the master file's source files for a while but it sometimes still fails.

Is it possible to make Adobe Fireworks to save it's master files with a different file extension than .png?

(So that it is similar to how you can use Photoshop to save it's files in a .psd file and web-optimized files are .png)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Fireworks can save its files only in Fw PNG layered (editable) file format, and the file extension is always **.png**. As a common convention between designers that use Fireworks, often a **.fw** is added before the **.png**, so a typical editable Adobe Fireworks file can have a file name like "**sample_filename.fw.png**". It's easy to remember that **.fw.png** files are *editable* and, as a bonus, you can still natively display them right in Explorer/Finder, preview them, view them in the browser, etc.

Maybe the next version of Adobe Fireworks (CS6) will have the option to save Fw PNG files by default with *.fw.png* file extension, but I'm not sure... :)

Comment: Turns out it does :) Yay CS6!